# AWS Autoscaling and ACL and Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Does ACLs effect auto scaling?

If i deny all traffic between two subnets within an VPC but the same two subnets are within same autoscaling group, will autoscaling work?

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling would still work. However the instances created by autoscaling would not be able to communicate with each other due to the ACL.